# How to use wkhtmltopdf with POST data

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I currently use `wkhtmltopdf` where I am attempting to generate a `.pdf` file after a user submits a form on our website.  The form data gets submitted to `post.php`, where it displays nicely as a formatted web page. I want to generate a .pdf file of this exact page.

But the problem begins when trying to execute `wkhtmltopdf`. I get a continuous loop because I'm trying to generate the .pdf from inside of this `post.php` file, which is also the target.

I have also tried to `include()` a separate `PHP` file to handle the `exec()` function, but I still get a continous loop.

Maybe a visual below helps:

`form.php` which contains something like below...

```
<form id="ecard" action="post.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="ecard_message" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

`post.php` which holds the posted data and contains `HTML` like so...

```
    <div class="content">
        <?php echo $_POST['ecard_message']; ?>
    </div>

    <?php exec("wkhtmltopdf http://example.com/post.php ecard.pdf"); ?>
```

My code DOES work when the `exec()` function is runs separately from these files, but how would I accomplish the `exec()` within this same process, automatically?

Any insight is very much appreciated.

Comment: *Hm.....* ajax maybe?

Comment: @Fred -ii-, That is def a possibility and considering it.  I keep thinking there's a better way via PHP, but maybe not. Where would I place the ajax in the workflow?

Comment: Inside another `<div>...</div>` where you have the exec or put everything inside the present div. Plus, if your exec'd file doesn't have some form of "exit', then that could be another reason why it's looping.

Comment: I'm not familiar on how/when to use `exit()`, so you would need to show me, but I'm def willing to try it.

Comment: Inside the exec file you're running, there should be an `exit;` where the process finishes. TBH, I'm not too familiar with `exec()` since I've never used it, but it would make sense if there would be one somewhere, after the line(s) where the process successfully finishes its work.

Answer (score 0):

calling `wkhtmltopdf http://example.com/post.php ecard.pdf` will lose the post data, so even if it worked, the pdf will be empty.

Rather generate the pdf as html and then pass it to wkhtmltopdf. Eg: *(untested)*

```
<?php
  $html = '<div class="content">' . $_POST['ecard_message'] . '</div>';
  exec("echo $html | wkhtmltopdf - ecard.pdf");
?>
```

See [Is there any wkhtmltopdf option to convert html text rather than file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864382/is-there-any-wkhtmltopdf-option-to-convert-html-text-rather-than-file) for explanation of using text instead of files.